# Skip Second String Between Characters with Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've been working on a regex issue. I have a lot of lines formatted like this:

```
3240985|#Apple.-+240538|34346|346356356|36433565|6agf8s89auf
```

The end goal should look like this:

```
#Apple.-+240538|6agf8s89auf
```

`#Apple.-+240538` is random characters, and `6agf8s89auf` is random alphanumeric characters.

I've been using `(.*?)[\|]` and replacing the parts I need with blank characters in Notepad++ but it's impossible to complete it this way with the number of lines I have.

Comment: is `Words` your actual text or is it representing dictionary words?

Comment: @rD. "Words" is a string, with all different characters.

Comment: and you want `numbers` and `No` to be removed?

Comment: @rD. Yes, just want to end up with `Words|Words`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for this kind of string is `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\|))(\d+(?:$|\|))`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sO0fZ2/2

However Find and Replace in Notepad++ may have some issues because Notepad++ finds and replace strings only once. Some other text editors like, sublime text find and replaces the contents recursively. However you can simple overcome this by clicking Replace All button multiple times.

**Input**

[image: Input Notepad++]

**Result** *after clicking "Replace All in All Opened Documents" twice*

[image: Output Notepad++]

In sublime text, you can achieve this in single click:

**Input**

[image: Input Sublime Text]

**Result**

[image: Output Sublime Text]

*P.S.: I'm not aware if there's any feature in Notepad++ that finds and replaces the content recursively. You can google for that. If there's any feature like that, then you can use it. However, I think that this shouldn't be a problem because it will only require a couple of more clicks.*

Comment: "No" is actually numbers. And the last "Words" is alphanumeric.

Comment: @NicholasChaffee can you give actual input?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NicholasChaffee: 2 unanchored lookbehinds inside an alternation group make this regex inefficient. Please check my straight-forward alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple approach with an **alternation**:

```
^\d+\||\|\d+(?=\||$)
```

**Details**:

- `^\d+\|` - Branch 1 matching a chunk of 1+ digits (`\d+`) at the beginning of the string (`^`) and a `|` after them
- `|` - alternation operator meaning *OR*
- `\|\d+(?=\||$)` - a literal pipe (`\|`, must be escaped) with 1+ digits after it (`\d+`) that are followed with a literal pipe or end of string (`(?=...)` is a positive lookahead that does not advance the regex index, thus, you can still match adjacent matches with the same pattern.)

[image]